# Is there a proof that the sum of the trihedral angles of a tetrahedron is minimal when the latter is regular?

Tags: trigonometry

Since the sum of the 6 dihedral angles is always 1 sphere more than the sum of the 4 trihedral angles, both sums are maximized or minimized at the same time.

I showed that for all four extremal tetrahedra that i can think of, the sum is greater than for a regular tetrahedron. I tried to prove the theorem by calculus, using Lagrange multipliers, but the calculation is totally intractable. Is there a simple proof, or any proof?

It would seem the minimal and maximal sums should occur for the regular case, or for one of the four extremal tetrahedra (two flattened and two elongated), but I can't prove that.

Answer (score 2):

The result is false. See

Thomas Egger/Rudolf Fritsch/Karl Seebach
Zum Winkelsummensatz für Tetraeder
Didaktik der Mathematik 1, 1983 (14-35)

or

THE SUMS OF THE DIHEDRAL AND TRIHEDRAL ANGLES IN A TETRAHEDRON
J.W.GADDUM
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 59, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1952), pp. 370-371
[JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2306805)

(Added by @Blue.) The latter reference demonstrates that the dihedral angle sum is bounded by $2\pi$ and $3\pi$, and that these bounds cannot be improved. (The lower bound is achieved by a "flat" tetrahedron whose edges are those of a plane quadrilateral and its diagonals: four dihedral angles have measure $0$, and two have measure $\pi$.) We see in particular, then, that the regular tetrahedron cannot be minimizing, as its angle sum is 
$$6\cdot\operatorname{acos}\frac{1}{3} = 7.38576\ldots > 2\pi$$